# test machine learning model with categorical variable in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, categorical-data

I have a data set like this

[image]

As you can see there is one categorical variable which is state

later I encode categorical variable

[image]

If I want to test my model with specific data I do something like this

```
print(regressor.predict([[1,0,1000,2000,3000]]))
```

Which works fine . But what I want to do is , while testing I directly want to input the city name , like `New York` or `Florida`

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 3):

A machine learning model can only work on numeric data. This is the reason why you had to encode your "states".
There are few ways to achieve what you are saying:
a) Use a function to return encoded value of the "state" while you can enter something like

```
print(regressor.predict([[1,0,1000,func("New York"),3000]]))
```

b) Use implicit encoding, which creates as many columns for each categorical variable implicitly.

Answer (score 3):

since ML model inputs only numbers, you have to do encoding even for the test dataset and then pass it to the model.

Answer (score 3):

You could use scikit-Learn [LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html#sklearn-preprocessing-labelencoder) for transforming and inverse transforming the categorical value.

***i.e.)***

```
>>> from sklearn import preprocessing
>>> le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
>>> le.fit(["New York", "Florida", "US", "Florida", "New York"])
LabelEncoder()
>>> le.transform(["New York", "Florida", "US", "Florida", "New York"]) 
array([0, 0, 1, 2]...)
>>> le.inverse_transform([0])
"New York"
```

You can call your function like below.

```
print(regressor.predict([[1,0,1000,le.transform(["New York"])[0],3000]]))
```

Comment: ```LabelEncoder``` is used specifically for labels only. Its not advised to use it for this purpose. I would advise to use [```sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder```](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) instead.

Comment: @VedangWaradpande I totally agree

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned before, any model takes only numbers as inputs. For this reason, usually we create a preprocessing function which can be applied to both the train and test sets at once.

In this case, you need to define a function which transforms the input vector into a numerical vector which can be further fed to your machine learning model:

```
Inputs -> Preprocessing -> Model
```

This preprocessing needs to be just like what you used for training so that you achieve the results you want to.

So typically when you create a model, your complete 'Model' can actually be a wrapper around the actual model that you use. For instance:

```
class MyModel():

    def __init__(self,):
        # Inputs and other variables like hyperparameters
        self.model = Model() # Initialise a model of your choice

    def preprocess(self, list_to_preprocess):
        # Preprocess this list

    def train(self, train_set):
        X_train, y_train = preprocess(X_train)
        self.model.fit(X_train, y_train)

    def predict(self, test_set):
        # If X_test is a vector, reshape and then preprocess

        X_test, y_test = preprocess(test_set)
        pred = self.model.predict(X_test)

        # Evaluate using pred and y_test
```

So finally to predict you use the function `MyModel.predict()` and not `Model.predict()` to achieve what you want to.

Answer (score 1):

This is not elegant at all, but you can just write `if... elif` statement depending on the input, like:

```
a = input("Please enter the state: ") 
if a = "New York":
    print(regressor.predict([[1,0,1000,2000,3000]]))
elif a = "Florida":
    print(regressor.predict([[0,1,1000,2000,3000]]))
else:
    print("Invalid state selected")
```